How to make custom user control able store content?
I have custom UserControl which is a Grid with a horizontal stripe and an ItemsControl, which has an Item template consisting of two Ellipse and a TextBlock.
The class representing the Item is the Step class. I need to be able to add Item instances directly inside XAML without resorting to C#.
Step class:
public class Step
{
    public Step() { Name = string.Empty; }
    public Step(string name, Brush color) { Name = name; InnerColor = color; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brush InnerColor { get; set; }
    public Brush OuterColor { get; set; }
    public Brush CompletedColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}

StepProgressBar:
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Height ="7" Fill="#FF00A8FF" Margin="10,0,1830,0">

    </Rectangle>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Steps">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,15,0,0"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>

                <StackPanel MaxWidth="75">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="EllipseOuter"  Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#FF00A8FF" />
                        <Ellipse x:Name="EllipseInner"  Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding InnerColor}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="EllipseInner" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding CompletedColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="EllipseInner" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding InnerColor}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

I need to get something like that in MainWindow.xaml:
    <Grid>
        <local:StepProgressBar x:Name="FirmwareBar" Margin="0,0,0,0">
          <local:Step Name="Test" InnerColor="Yellow" IsCompleted="false" />
          <local:Step Name="Test1" InnerColor="Green" IsCompleted="true" CompletedColor="#FF7DEEAF" />
        </local:StepProgressBar>
        
    </Grid>

I tried to use ContentControl, as advised in one of the similar topics, but I did not figure out exactly how and in what order I should place the elements in this case.

You need to modify your Code behind of your custom user control. Add a property called Items of type ObservableCollection<Step>. If this collection changes, you should update your ItemsControl:
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Step> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Step>();

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items .CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Steps.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            Steps.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

In your XAML, you can add items to your user control via
<local:StepProgressBar x:Name="FirmwareBar" Margin="0,0,0,0">
     <local:StepProgrssBar.Items>
          <local:Step Name="Test" InnerColor="Yellow" IsCompleted="false" />
          <local:Step Name="Test1" InnerColor="Green" IsCompleted="true" CompletedColor="#FF7DEEAF" />
    </local:StepProgrssBar.Items>
</local:StepProgressBar>

There might be a more elegant way which does not always completely clear the items of the ItemsControl and adds the whole collection again, but only modifies the items that actually have been changed in your ObservableCollection. But if you do not have a lot of entries and if they don't change very often, there will only be a small difference.

Try to use ContentPropertyAttribute to have 2 less lines, example.

Note that when items are supposed to be added only when the XAML is parsed (and not any later, as the question seems to suggest), you do not need an ObservableCollection. Besides that, your current implementation ignores the elements in the Items collection after InitializeComponent has been executed.
